# How to recover .profile on Mac OS?

Tags: terminal, macos

I have mis-configured ~/.profile while adding new environment variable. I want to restore my original .profile for my Mac OS, I am not mac expert please help me. None of my shell command is working for me like ls, java, php etc Please help

Comment: Get it from your backup ? If on Lion what editor did you use as Versions might have it. (For original .profile just delete it)

Answer (score 3):

[Show hidden files in Finder](http://guides.macrumors.com/Viewing_hidden_files_on_a_Mac). Then you can either fix the problem in TextEdit, or simply remove/rename the file. There is no default `~/.profile` on Mac OS X, only a global `/etc/profile` (and you may also have a `~/.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 0):

If you still get to the shell prompt, you can use `: > ~/.profile` to create a new and empty file. Afterwards open a new shell in Terminal (by opening a new tab or window) and your environment should work again.

In addition: When editing .profile (or .bash_profile) it is always helpful to open a shell (terminal window) *before* you start editing. So even if you mess up the edit, you still have a working shell to fix issues (because .profile is only read once at start so further edits don't impact a running shell unless you source .profile again). And as usual: **make backups**.